# How do I create a method that capitalizes the first letter of a string in java?

Tags: java, methods, cpu-word, capitalize

what I'm trying to do is write a method that has one argument and returns a new string that capitalises that string and returns in its parameter.

this is my code so far:

```
 public void input(){

    this.printmessage("Dillon", "Francis", "chimes", "chimes from hudson mohawke", "2",             "$69.00", "$420.00", "$1337.00");
}


public void printmessage(String firstName, String lastname, String product, String company, String number, String retail, String price, String saving){

    UI.println("text " + firstName + ",");



    UI.println(text + " " + product + "s text, text text text text -");



    UI.println(" ");
}
```

What I want to do is capitalise the product parameter (chimes) and then return into into the printMessage capitalized if it is used at the beginning of a sentence.

Will something like this work?

```
 public String capitalise(String product){

    return Character.toUpperCase(product.charAt(0)) + product.substring(1);

}
```

I'm really stuck and would love some help.

Thanks.

I've tried this

```
 String pls = (product + " example");
    if ( pls.startsWith(product) ) {
        product = capitalise(product); 
   }
   UI.println(pls);
```

but it doesnt print out the capitalised version.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't help me mate.

Comment: Well, your solution works (congrats! :-)) but you could have tested that your self isn't it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This might sound silly, but how do I call it in the printMessage?

Comment: Now _that_ you could have added to the question itself. (Hint: use `@` and then the name of the user you want to inform)

Comment: `Will something like this work?` How about you try it...

Comment: @ambigram_maker  thanks mate haha. So How would I take the new capitalized string and add It into the printmessage?

Comment: @mikeyaworski thanks for taking a look, my problem is I don't know how to call that new string into my printmessage method.

Comment: @2nd Then point that out in your question.

Comment: @mikeyaworski sorry about that, I will next time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line :

`UI.println(text + " " + product + "s text, text text text text -");`

to:

`UI.println(text + " " + capitalize(product) + "s text, text text text text -");`

But your code needs a bit more structuring. Focus on even indentation. And if you need the capitalized `product` later on, you'd better save it before you use it, like

```
...
product = capitalize(product);
UI.println(text + " " + product + "s text, text text text text -");
...
```

---

EDIT:

For this I'm assuming the *line* is contained in a `String` called `line`.

First check if the `line` begins with `product`. Then capitalize it.

```
...
String line = text + " " + product + "s text, text text text text -";
line = line.trim(); // removes whitespaces.
if ( line.startsWith( product ) ) {
    product = capitalize ( product ); //or whatever.
}
UI.println(line);
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate. I know it's a bit messy at the momment, I've cleaned it up :)

Comment: Well, don't forget to accept the answer. :-)

Comment: I know it might be a bit extra, but how do I make it so the capitalize part check that the "product" is the first string/word in a sentence and only capitalises it if it is?

Comment: @2nd Take a look, tell me if you don't understand.

Comment: Okay, I understand that code. However, I'm using UI.println to write the text to console. I cant seem to get it to check that.  I've tried if (printmessage.startsWith(Product) but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: You have to _create_ a line. (Implement it correctly... Is there any chance that `text` is an empty `String`? I've assumed that and written my code accordingly.)

Comment: i've tried it (edit up top), but I can't get it to print out the capitalised version :(.